# Using Excel vba to put objects in PowerPoint table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

I'm using an Excel worksheet to populate a meeting schedule in PowerPoint. My excel file has columns a through f (meeting name, location, category (which staff section runs the meeting), days of week, time of day, and length of meeting). The headers for the worksheet are in row 4 so the data starts in row 5. This data is used to put PowerPoint shapes into a table on a slide. I have a class object called `BREpptObjects` that has `BREpptObjectName As String, BREpptObjectLocation As String, BREpptObjectCategory As String, BREpptObjectDays as String, BREpptObjectTime As Integer, BREpptObjectLength As Double, BREpptObjectPIC As Integer`. PIC is supposed to be position in cell for multiple objects in the same cell. All the Gets and Lets are coded also. Leaving that out for brevity.

I have a command button on my spreadsheet to initiate the export. The problem is if there are multiple meeting at the same time my shapes are stacking on top of each other. For the life of me I can't figure out how to offset or deconflict the stacked shapes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub ExportToPPTButton_Click()

Dim BREobjects() As BREpptObjects
Dim BREdaysString() As String

Dim BREppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim BREpptURL As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim BREpptLayout As CustomLayout
Dim NewBREslide As Slide
Dim BREtable As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim BREbubble As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim BREdtg As Range
Dim placeInCell As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim BREitems as Range
Dim yy As Single
Dim xx As Single
Dim dx As Single
Dim dy As Single
Dim count As Integer
Dim objInCell As Integer
Dim daysAsInt As Integer

Dim BREname As String
Dim BRELocation As String
Dim BREcategory As String
Dim BREtime As Long
Dim BRElength As Double
Dim BREdays As String

BREpptURL = "https://MyURL.com"

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set BREppt = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(BREpptURL)
Set BREpptLayout = BREppt.Slides(1).CustomLayout
Set NewBREslide = BREppt.Slides.AddSlide(1, BREpptLayout)
Set BREtable = BREppt.Slides(2).Shapes("BREslideTable")

lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

Set BREitems = Range("a5:a" & lastrow)

BREtable.Copy
BREppt.Slides(1).Shapes.Paste
BREppt.Slides(1).Select

Set NewBREslide = BREppt.Slides(1)
Set BREtable = BREppt.Slides(1).Shapes("BREslideTable")

placeInCell = 0
For Each i In BREitems
    ReDim Preserve BREobjects(i.Row - 4)
    Set BREobjects(i.Row - 4) = New BREpptObjects

    With BREobjects(i.Row - 4)
        .BREname = Cells(i.row, "a").value
        .BRELocation = Cells(i.row, "b").value
        .BREcategory = Cells(i.row, "c").value
        .BREdays = Cells(i.row, "d").value
        .BREtime = (Cells(i.row, "e").value / 100) + 2           'this sets the time to equal the row number in the powerpoint table
        .BRElength = Cells(i.row, "f").value
    End With

    BREname = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREname
    BRELocation = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BRELocation
    BREcategory = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREcategory
    BREtime = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREtime
    BRElength = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BRElength
    BREdays = BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREdays

    yy = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, 4).Shape.Top
    dy = BREtable.Table.Cell(BRetime, 4).Shape.Height * BRElength

    Set BREdtg = Range("d5:d" & lastrow)
    BREdaysString() = Split(BREdays, ", ")

    count = 0
    For Each j In BREdaysString
        Dim BREcompareString1 As String
        BREcompareString1 = "*" & j & "*"
        objInCell = 0

        For Each k in BREdtg
            Dim BREcompareTime As Long
            Dim BREcompareString2 As String

            BREcompareTime = (Cells(k.row, "e").value / 100) + 2
            BREcompareString2 = k.value

            If UCase(BRecompareString2) Like UCase(BREcompareString1) And BREtime = BREcompareTime Then
                objInCell = objInCell + 1
            End If
        Next k

        If objInCell = 1 Then
            BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREpic = 1
        ElseIf objInCell > 1 Then
            count = count + 1
            BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREpic = objInCell       'I know this causes the stacking but everything else I've tried blows us all the other powerpoint bubbles. 
        End If                                             'I feel like the count integer could be used somehow to set the BREpic but I can't figure out the loops.

        If j = "Monday" Then                               'This will set the column number in the table for the objects.
            daysAsInt = 4
        ElseIf j = "Tuesday" Then
            daysAsInt = 5
        ElseIf j = "Wednesday" Then
            daysAsInt = 6
        ElseIf j = "Thursday" Then
            daysAsInt = 7
        ElseIf j = "Friday" Then
            daysAsInt = 8
        ElseIf j = "Saturday" Then
            daysAsInt = 9
        ElseIf j = "Sunday" Then
            daysAsInt = 10
        End If

        dx = BREtable.Table.Columns(4).Width / objInCell

        If BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREpic = 1 Then
            xx = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Left
        ElseIf BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREpic > 1 Then
            xx = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Left + (dx * BREobjects(i.Row - 4).BREpic) - dx
        End If

        Set BREbubble = NewBREslide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectable, xx, yy, dx, dy)

        With BREbubble
            .Name = BREname
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = BREname
        End With

    Next j
Erase BREdaysString
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's always worthwhile to test if something can be done manually before coding it. In your case, PowerPoint tables don't accept shapes or drawing objects, only text. So if you need to organize shapes, a table is the wrong tool. You would have to calculate all the shape sizes and positions, then offset each one, which will mess up your calendar grid. Are you sure you can't do this by pasting text instead of shapes?

Comment: I know this is overengineered. A tool really isn't required to manage bubbles on a calendar slide. But it's the choice of the command to use this format. The slide has to look the same. The sizes all populate correctly. It's just the shapes with objInCell > 1 that stack on top of each other. Isn't there a way to loop through the shapes where the object.left = otherObject.left and off set just those?

Comment: This isn't correct, obvi, but I was thinking something like after `Set BREbubble...` I could have a loop something like:

`
If BREbubble.Width <> BREtable.Table.Columns(daysAsInt).Width Then
        For k = 1 to NewBREslide.Shapes.count
              If BREbubble.left = NewBREslide.Shapes(k).left and BREbubble.Width = NewBREslide.Shapes(k).Width Then
                    BREbubble.IncrementLeft (-BREbubble.Width)
               End If
         Next k
End If
`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was suggesting, getting the shape sizes and positions and moving them. Without seeing your calendar, it's hard to know, but it also might be worth looking at scripting a piece of SmartArt, since those shapes automatically remain adjacent instead of stacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, lost my computer to the helpdesk for about a month. Got it back finally, about a week ago. I had a lightbulb go off while my computer was sequestered. Spent about half a day working my idea and got this code to work. I won't post the BREpptObject class for brevity, but it's all there with the appropriate Gets and Lets. Here's the solution:

```
Sub ExportToPPTButton_Click()

Dim BREppt As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim BREpptURL As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim BREpptLayout As CustomLayout
Dim NewBREslide As Slide
Dim BREtable As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim BREbubble As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim BREdtg As Range

Dim yy As Single
Dim dy As Single

BREpptURL = "https://SHAREPOINT.URL"

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set BREppt = PowerPoint.Presentations.Open(BREpptURL)
Set BREpptLayout = BREppt.Slides(1).CustomLayout
Set NewBREslide = BREppt.Slides.AddSlide(1, BREpptLayout)
Set BREtable = BREppt.Slides(2).Shapes("BREslideTable")
Set BREdata = Range("a5:f" & lastrow)
Set BREitems = Range("a5:a" & lastrow)

BREtable.Copy
BREpptSlides(1).Shapes.Paste
BREppt.Slides(1).Select

Set NewBREslide = BREppt.Slides(1)
Set BREtable = BREppt.Slides(1).Shapes("BREslideTable")

'creates a new object for each BRE day/time comvination
count = 0
For Each i In BREitems
    BREdaysString() = Split(Cells(i.Row, "d"), ", ")
    For Each j In BREdaysString

        count = count + 1
        ReDim Preserve BREopbjects(count)
        Set BREobjects(count) = New BREpptObjects

        With BREobjects(count)
            .BREname = Cells(i.Row, "a").value
            .BRELocation = Cells(i.Row, "b").value
            .BRECategory = Cells(i.Row, "c").value
            .BREdays = j
            .BREtime = (Cells(i.Row, "e").value / 100) + 2
            .BRElength = Cells(i.Row, "f").value
        End With
    Next j
    Erase BREdaysString
Next i

'compares each BREobject to all other BREobjects to determine how many and which are in the same day/time
For i = 1 To UBound(BREobjects)

    BREname = BREobjects(i).BREname
    BRELocation = BREobjects(i).BRELocation
    BRECategory = BREobjects(i).BRECategory
    BREtime = BREobjects(i).BREtime
    BRElength = BREobjects(i).Length
    BREdays = BREobjects(i).BREdays

    If IsEmpty(BREobjects(i).BREpic) Then
        BREobjects(i).BREpic = 0
    End If

    objInCell = 0
    For j = 1 To UBoung(BREobjects)
        BREnameComapre = BREobjects(j).BREname
        BRELocationComapre = BREobjects(j).BRELocation
        BRECategoryComapre = BREobjects(j).BRECategory
        BREtimeComapre = BREobjects(j).BREtime
        BRElengthComapre = BREobjects(j).Length
        BREdaysComapre = BREobjects(j).BREdays

        If BREdaysCompare = BREdays And BREtimeCompare = BREtime Then           'Sets place in cell (PIC) for each objects
            objInCell = objInCell + 1
            BREobjects(j).BREpic = objInCell
        End If
    Next j
    BREobjects(i).BREobjInCell = objInCell                                      'Sets total # of objects in cell
Next i

'Converts day of the week to column number and creates bubbles for ppt slide
For i = 1 To UBound(BREobjects) - LBound(BREobjects)

    BREdays = BREobjects(i).BREdays
    BREpic = BREobjects(i).BREpic
    BREtime = BREobjects(i).BREtime
    BRECategory = BREobjects(i).BRECategory
    BREname = BREobjects(i).BREname

    objInCell = BREobjects(i).objInCell

    If BREdays = "Monday" Then
        daysAsInt = 4
    ElseIf BREdays = "Tuesday" Then
        daysAsInt = 5
    ElseIf BREdays = "Wednesday" Then
        daysAsInt = 6
    ElseIf BREdays = "Thursday" Then
        daysAsInt = 7
    ElseIf BREdays = "Friday" Then
        daysAsInt = 8
    ElseIf BREdays = "Saturday" Then
        daysAsInt = 9
    ElseIf BREdays = "Sunday" Then
        daysAsInt = 10
    End If

    yy = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Top
    dy = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Height * BRElength
    dx = BREtable.Table.Columns(daysAsInt).Width / objInCell

    If objInCell = 1 Then
        xx = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Left
    ElseIf objInCell > 1 Then
        xx = BREtable.Table.Cell(BREtime, daysAsInt).Shape.Left + (dx * BREpic) - dx
    End If

    Set BREbubble = NewBREslide.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, xx, yy, dx, dy)

    With BREbubble
        .Name = BREname
        .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = BREname
        .TextFrame2.AutoSize = msoAutoSizeTextToFitShape
    End With

    If BRECategory = "CENTCOM" Then
        BREbubble.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(112, 48, 160)
        BREbubble.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf BRECategory = "CG Chair" Then
        BREbubble.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        BREbubble.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf BRECategory = "GO Chair" Then
        BREbubble.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 204, 0)
        BREbubble.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    ElseIf BRECategory = "Staff Chair" Then
        BREbubble.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        BREbubble.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```